# Access an internal site through an external site

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, firewall

I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is no, but I just wanted to get some feedback before I go down another path.

Here is my scenario.  I have two websites.  Website 1 is an internal website that cannot be accessed outside of our domain.  Website 2 is an external website that can be accessed outside of the domain, but has access to webservices inside of the domain.

My question is, is there any possible way to display the internal page through the external page without making the internal page external.

Answer (score 1):

You want to proxy certain external requests to the internal site, look into [IIS Proxy](http://www.iisproxy.net/).

Comment: Have to point out that this whole thing is one great big security hole.

Comment: In general, what the poster is suggesting is a bad idea, but I've found situations where proxies come in handy. For example, transitioning a website between new and old servers while maintaining fallback capabilities if files aren't found on the new server.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree that there are legitimate uses. I just wanted to go on record about the risk. There's a *reason* intranet sites aren't available from outside.